# Отключение звука в WebView JavaFX

Tags: javascript, javafx, webview

Всем привет, делаю лаунчер для своего проекта. В рамках проекта необходимо отключить звук при работе самого лаунчера или же при загрузке страницы в WebView.
Сам только начинаю учиться программированию. По этому можно сказать, что я ещё овощ.
Делаю на основе OpenSource проекта https://github.com/new-sashok724/Launcher
Имеется файл dialog.js располагающийся по адресу /Launcher/runtime/dialog/dialog.js#L14 [(Клик)](https://github.com/new-sashok724/Launcher/blob/19989e7685343f72940796580f332f56cd9550fe/Launcher/runtime/dialog/dialog.js#L14)

Товарищ предоставил код в двух вариантах ([java](https://pastebin.com/nuD1SXuM)) ([javaScript](https://pastebin.com/1XRKXCfN))

На данный момент код выглядит вот так ([клик](https://pastebin.com/gM0vM7yk))
После компиляции выдаёт следующую ошибку [(клик)](https://pastebin.com/TRnH1298)
Буду рад, если поможете.

Конкретно сам вопрос: Как необходимо исправить код ([клик](https://pastebin.com/gM0vM7yk)) чтобы при запуске программа не выдавала следующую ошибку [(клик)](https://pastebin.com/TRnH1298)

Сам учусь в 7 классе, информатика на уровне сделать презентацию.
Решил учится дополнительно

Comment: Words Задай вопрос конкретно по тему. Положи код в тему вопроса. Покажи, что у тебя не получается.

Comment: Так код я предоставил, проблему изложил. Не получается скомпилировать, выдаёт ошибку. Которую я тоже предоставил. Я не знаю, что в этом случае сделать. Пытался исправить ошибку, путём исправления синтаксиса, но ничего не выходит P.S (Прошу прощения за неграмотность в орфографическом и техническом плане)

Comment: Words На этом ресурсе принято задавать конкретный вопрос, затем приложить к этому вопросу код (не нужно пересылать на github). Никто не пойдет туда. Затем указать, что не получается.

Comment: Сам код, который необходим для решения вопроса (Как я считаю) лежит не на github, а на pastebin. GitHub я указал лишь для того, чтобы было удобно. Вдруг кому-то это может понадобиться

Comment: Words Самое интересное, что этот код может никому и не понадобится. У тебя есть проблема и ее нужно решить. Если хочешь получить ответ на проблему, следуй правилу.

Comment: Хорошо, что конкретно мне необходимо сделать? Чётко сформулировать вопрос, указать какие проблемы при его решении возникают и поставить код не на сторонний ресурс а под спойлер?

Comment: Words Совершенно верно. Запомни: Хороший ответ зависит от хорошего вопроса. Время - невозобновляемый ресурс. Никто не будет тратить свое время на решение твоей проблемы часами.